# i7 7700 processor showing only 4 cores and No of threads per core is 1

Tags: cpu, intel-core-i7, hyper-threading

I am a ubuntu user, when I type **lscpu** I got it as

```
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              4
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-3
Thread(s) per core:  1
Core(s) per socket:  4
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               158
Model name:          Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700 CPU @ 3.60GHz
Stepping:            9
CPU MHz:             3600.000
CPU max MHz:         3800.0000
CPU min MHz:         800.0000
BogoMIPS:            7200.00
Virtualization:      VT-x
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            256K
L3 cache:            8192K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-3
```

But in the intel website it says it supports 8 way multitasking and no of threads as 8.  Please help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem by enabling Hyperthreading in BIOS. It works perfectly now.